# how to use C# program using json data with the properties get and set and i have to display the data in a table format?

Tags: c#, json

How should i parse a json data in c#?

Comment: Good luck, let us know how you get on

Comment: Should probably give a bit more informations here

Answer (score 1):

i used JSON.NET

```
static void Main()
{
  string json = "{\"FullName\":\"Mr Ravikanth\",\"LastName\":Yavathae}";

    JObject parsed = JObject.Parse(json);

    foreach (var pair in parsed)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", pair.Key, pair.Value);
    }
}
```